# Realtime Blending UIImages

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, ios7, gpuimage

Is it possible to have realtime blending like the arrow in notification center on iOS 7?
I wonder if it is possible to have a UIImage blend with soft light with the content (UIView or CALayer) right underneath it, so the background image can move and the blended image would stay in one spot.

I want it to be where you can have a UIImage where you can set a blendMode property to whatever blend mode you need, such as, `imageView.blendMode = kCGBlendModeSoftLight;`

I tried using [GPUImage](https://github.com/bradlarson/gpuimage) but I could not figure out how to do what I need. Any help would be appreciated.

So far, the code I use to set the blend mode of a UIImage is this; however, if the background view is moved, the blend on the UIImage is not updated.

```
    //blur the background
    GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter *blurFilter = [[GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter alloc] init];
    blurFilter.blurRadiusInPixels = 50.0f;
    blurFilter.blurPasses = 4;
    UIImage *blurredBackground = [blurFilter imageByFilteringImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];

    //make the blended images
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, 2.0f);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGInterpolationHigh);
    [blurredBackground drawInRect:self.view.bounds blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"BarLineImage.png"] drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 31, self.view.bounds.size.width, 1) blendMode:kCGBlendModeSoftLight alpha:1.0];

    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Equalizer-th.png"] drawInRect:CGRectMake(65, self.view.bounds.size.height - 30, 30, 30) blendMode:kCGBlendModeSoftLight alpha:1.0];
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Player-th.png"] drawInRect:CGRectMake(145, self.view.bounds.size.height - 30, 30, 30) blendMode:kCGBlendModeSoftLight alpha:1.0];
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Container-th.png"] drawInRect:CGRectMake(225, self.view.bounds.size.height - 30, 30, 30) blendMode:kCGBlendModeSoftLight alpha:1.0];

    UIImage *blendedImages = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Here is a screenshot of what this code does for some visual aid.[image: Screenshot]

This looks the way I need it to but I cannot animate the content underneath the images at the bottom. I really need to be able to have realtime blending for UIImages and UIViews.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about how the "background view is moved"? Are you looking for a blur of the live video feed, or just whatever was on your screen when the blur took effect?

Comment: I am looking for a blend of the live video feed.

Comment: I think I understand what you are going for, and it's an interesting idea! Blurring the live video feed for the entire background is easy enough, just switch out the UIImage that you are currently blurring for a GPUImageVideoCamera which targets the blur filter, which target's the GPUImageView, much like the example projects. But your idea to blend the controls with the underlying video sounds appealing. I have an idea of how to accomplish this with a branched chain and some cropping. I'll play with it tonight and see if I can make it work. I'll let you know what I come up with!

Comment: Isn't GPUImageVideoCamera only for an actual live video? The background is not an actual video so I wonder how this can work.

Answer (score 0):

Check video number 226 from [WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/) session. You can find a lot of information how to animate, blend images using new iOS 7 api.

I realize that my answer is not complete and it should be a comment to question but my reputation is too low.

edit: 
WWDC Session 2013, Video nr 226: Implementing Engaging UI on iOS

Comment: It would be helpful to add the name of the video and session description especially if the link ever goes down.

Comment: The video does not talk about blend modes, nor does it give any examples on how to achieve a live blur or blend.